# Strange/Odd characters appear when calling library functions in Matlab

Tags: c, matlab, compiler-construction, shared-libraries

I'm using MATLAB to call functions from an external library to control a device,
the problem I have is that with specific function the arguments are not converted properly and strange characters appear in its place.

For example, calling:

```
    ERRCODE = calllib ('MEDAQLib','ExecSCmd',1,int8('Laser_On'));
```

where `ExecSCmd` arguments in `libfunctionview` are defined as `ulong,int8Ptr`

Now, when I log the commands this happens

> ExecSCmd, Enter, instanceHandle= 1, sensorCommand= 'Laser_On'“£~ð'
>   MESensor::SensorCommand, Enter, this= 0x30c07b50, S_Command=
>   Laser_On'“£~ð ErrorMsg::Error_SetText set, Message: -14
>   (ERR_UNKNOWN_SENSOR_COMMAND): Laser_On'“£~ð

Instead of `Laser_On'“£~ð` it's meant to show a clean `Laser_On` like it does with other functions. It gets weirder, sometimes calling this will randomly work, but done so very few times.

Similar issues arise when using a different computer, with same Matlab version, same compiler, same library, but different OS.
The compiler used is Windows SDK 7.1, Matlab Version 2012b.

Why do these weird characters appear in the arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the library expects the string to be zero-terminated, like a string in C. You could try `int8(['Laser_On', char(0)])` instead. Indeed, the [reference](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/passing-arguments-to-shared-library-functions.html) says that your array is passed as what C denotes by `char *`, a pointer to the first character `'L'` of your string. Instead of using just `int8`, you could also write more consisely `int8(char(['Laser_On', 0]))`.

The strange characters appear because the logger in your library prints one character after another until it reaches a zero byte. Thus, behavior becomes undefined in your case and you have the logger print those odd characters until it hits zero by chance.

Comment: Very well explained! I understand now. I don't have the chance to test this right now, but this will probably work. Just one thing, I think the function input still requires integer format on Matlab, thus: `int8 (char['Laser_On',0])` should do. Ill confirm if this works soon.

Comment: Thanks much for your feedback. In case you find out that only `int8` works, you could edit my answer.